# Мы меняем наше имя (обратно) на Stack Overflow

Tags: поддержка, перевод-блога

## Мы — Stack Overflow

Вы, скорее всего, знаете нас по сайтам Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow Careers, другим сайтам сети Stack Exchange или из поисковой выдачи Google.

### Кратко: мы меняем название компании

**Что изменится:**

1. С сегодняшнего дня наша компания будет называться Stack Overflow.
2. Незначительно изменится логотип.
3. Всё, больше ничего.

**Что же такое «Stack Overflow»:**

- Сообщество, в котором миллионы программистов задают вопросы и делятся знаниями с коллегами.
- Лучшее место для поиска работы для программистов или поиска талантливых разработчиков.
- Флагман сети вопросов и ответов Stack Exchange по более чем 140 тематикам.
- (обновление!) Компания, которая кроется за всем этим.

В этот день семь лет назад [Джоэл анонсировал запуск Stack Overflow](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). С момента запуска стратегия команды сводилась к созданию полезных инструментов для разработчиков, и в случае если они работали, мы делали их доступными для более широкого круга профессий. Мы считаем, что новое имя компании лучше отражает исходную философию и поможет сделать больше хорошего как для программистов, так и для других специалистов.

В общем-то, это всё. Но на всякий случай я попробую ответить на вопросы, которые, скорее всего, могли у вас возникнуть.

### В: Итак, что всё-таки изменится?

С сегодняшнего дня мои коллеги и я будем говорить «Я работаю в Stack Overflow». Предполагаю, нам даже будут нужны новые визитки. Надеюсь, этим уже кто-то занимается. Секундочку, мы отходим от темы. В течение нескольких следующих недель мы изменим название во многих местах, например, в блоге, подкасте и многих других, где мы ссылались на компанию, как на «Stack Exchange». Сеть вопросов и ответов по-прежнему будет носить имя «Stack Exchange».

#### В: Сеть Stack Exchange больше никогда не будет такой, как раньше?

Нет. *И еще раз нет.*

[image: mg]

Наш вклад в развитие Сети Stack Exchange останется неизменным, мы будем и далее инвестировать в её развитие. Участники сайтов Stack Exchange построили сеть сообществ конструктивной взаимопомощи небывалых масштабов. Мы безумно рады быть частью этого. Позвольте представить несколько фактов, отражающих то, как много вы достигли:

- Сеть в целом имеет в 5 раз больше *авторов сообщений* в месяц, чем англоязычная Википедия *редакторов* за тот же период.
- Stack Exchange находится на [47-м месте по посещаемости в США](https://www.quantcast.com/top-sites) *без учета Stack Overflow*. При этом имеет примерно одинаковое с New York Times количество просмотров в месяц.

[Вот что думают наши инвесторы](https://medium.com/@cdixon/a16z-leads-40m-investment-in-stack-exchange-a84b6c1b9122) по данному вопросу:

> Я верю, что скорость роста Stack Exchange сейчас достигла второй космической. Мы ожидаем, что не только существующие тематики продолжат расти, но и будут появляться многие новые до тех пор, пока Сеть не покроет все разделы знаний, которые можно представить в виде вопросов и ответов. По мере появления нового поколения людей, выросшего с Интернетом, привычки поиска информации в книгах, руководствах использования или обращения за советом к друзьям исчезнут.
>
> ​                                    --Chris Dixon, Andreessen Horowitz

Книги, вы слышали?! Мы идем за вами, вы, 53-летние анахронизмы.

### В: Всё же, зачем менять?

**Мы начинали с идеи лучшего сайта вопросов и ответов для разработчиков.**

В то время когда мы дали название «Stack Exchange» компании, мы занимались развитием *исключительно* сайтов вопросов и ответов. Stack Overflow имел настолько широкий успех, что мы приняли решение модифицировать движок так, чтобы предоставить возможность людям делиться знаниями на отличные от программирования темы. Как результат, лучшим вариантом имени компании для нас было название Сети. Если бы мы решили создать диаграмму отношений проектов и попросили бы нарисовать её непредрасположенного к рисованию ребенка, она бы выглядела так:

[image: img 2]

Подчеркну, вопросы и ответы *остаются* нашим главным продуктом, и мы продолжим делать всё возможное, чтобы во всем мире они помогали [разработчикам](https://stackoverflow.com/), [химикам](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), [фотографам](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) и, конечно же, [этим удивительным людям](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

**Затем мы сосредоточились на достойной *работе* для разработчиков.**

Для нас было кристально ясно, что хотя хорошие разработчики ценились крайне высоко, большинство сайтов поиска работы спроектированы для удовлетворения нужд  *специалистов по подбору персонала* и были переполнены вакансиями «с зарплатой от 50 до 500 тысяч в месяц» и требованиями к кандидату «от 8 лет опыта разработки на Swift». Устали от этого бреда? Мы тоже. В результате мы создали [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/why-stack), что *вполне* вписывается в мою концепцию структуры компании. Но Джоэл настаивал:

> «Мы должны быть одержимы идеей создания лучших инструментов для разработчиков, а не рисовать непонятные диаграммы. Зарубите это себе на носу, или я отберу ваш рабочий стол с регулируемой высотой и попрошу повара более не давать вам сладкого.»

Но я *все равно* не мог найти правильного места «Карьере». Получилось так, что я постоянно застревал непонятно где. И поскольку Джоэл упомянул «одержимы» множество раз, я добавил изображение Бэтмена, поскольку, будучи подростком, я не знал никого более одержимого.

[image: img]

**Что дальше? *ВСЁ* лучшее для разработчиков.**

Это привело нас к тому, что мы имеем сегодня. Мы просто могли бы пожинать лавры и радоваться тому, чего уже достигли. На самом деле я предложил именно так и поступить, но вы же знаете Джоэла:

> «Знаешь, когда ты сможешь пожинать лавры? Когда *все* проблемы разработчиков будут решены. На прошлой неделе Джон Кармак добавил в Инстаграм то, как он ест вчерашний бутерброд. *Ты ему всё портишь.*»

Честно говоря, какое-то время я беспокоился за Джоэла, но он подтолкнул меня к мысли:

#### У разработчиков есть *множество* проблем.

Мы пришли к тому, что сосредоточились на проблемах разработчиков, и попросили объединиться все мировое сообщество программистов для решения этих задач. На мой взгляд, если бы мы решились создать лучшую платформу вопросов и ответов для *всех*, она была бы полезна *никому*. За счет концентрации нашего внимания на небольшой группе тех, кому мы действительно могли помочь, у нас получилось создать продукт, *который по праву можно назвать выдающимся*.

Мы собираемся придерживаться плана: каждый раз в поисках нового способа услужить нашим пользователям мы будем концентрироваться на том, что умеем лучше всего — решать проблемы разработчиков. В данный момент мы работаем над нашим крупнейшим проектом с момента запуска Stack Overflow — документацией. Вы можете узнать более подробно о ней [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/) или [зарегистрироваться на участие в бете](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform) и стать частью того, что, по нашему мнению, будет следующим крупным прорывом.

Хочу подчеркнуть, что на своем пути мы допустили множество ошибок, но каждый раз, когда у нас что-то получалось, мы пытались решить именно проблемы разработчиков. Добившись успеха в чём-то, мы масштабировали решение на все остальные тематики. Мы хотим и дальше двигаться этим курсом и были бы рады, если бы и вы шли вместе с нами.

Примерно так думает «ребенок с карандашом» о том, как мы выглядим сегодня.

[image: img]

Хочу ли я увидеть больше цветных (плохо нарисованных) изображений наших продуктов для разработчиков на рисунке? Конечно же, да! Получится ли? Уверен. Но, как и всегда, мы рассчитываем на то, что вы поможете нам выяснить это.

### Мне показалось, или вы говорили что-то про логотип?

Да, действительно. За исключением незначительных деталей, хорошо знакомый вам логотип Stack Overflow, за который мы заплатили [512 долларов на конкурсе 99 Designs](http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774/entries) много лет назад, и это были *большие деньги* для нас, был неизменен. Мы считали и считаем его прекрасным. Команда дизайнеров внесла лишь небольшие изменения. На следующей неделе ребята расскажут нам, как логотип вписывается в новый стиль, который мы планируем использовать для стандартизации визуального представления.

В завершение. Вдохновившись видео, где Google объясняет, как они пришли к концепту логотипа «детсадовских букв, большинство из которых правильно выровнены», мы создали своё. Хоть в нашем и нет фразы «… и только правая небольшая толика причуды», всё же оно очень похоже на оригинальное. На мой взгляд, видео отлично демонстрирует, как изменился наш логотип.

[image: img]https://youtu.be/uipTZ2re4Uk

(Видео записано Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe, ака [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha?tab=profile), музыка [Zero Project](https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/340121/zero-project))

#### Мы - Stack Overflow. Мы были бы никем без всех вас.

---

<sub>Это *свободный перевод* [публикации](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) [@Jaydles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles)</sub>

Comment: Я не очень понял с названием. Что поменялось? "Stack Exchange" на "Stack Overflow"?

Comment: @tutankhamun Да, именно так, название компании изменилось с "Stack Exchange" на "Stack Overflow".

Comment: А помимо названия что-то поменялось? В чём была причина смены названия? В принципе, какая разница как называется компания?