# Каким критериям должен соответствовать участник сообщества для избрания в модераторы?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, выборы

**Дано:**

В чате какие-то разговоры о модераторах, выборах и критериях, а чёткой инфы о том, по каким показателям определяется достоин человек сего звания или нет я с ходу не нашёл.

**Вопросы:**

1. Каковы формальные критерии соответствия высокому званию модератора?
2. Какова процедура избрания?
3. Права?
4. Обязанности?

Comment: По третьему пункту заметил, что метку `faq` немодераторам, например, добавить нельзя.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: на всякий случай - ссылка требования к модераторам на enSO http://stackoverflow.com/election/6

Comment: Всем спасибо, но таки каковы у нас будут критерии с учётом местной специфики? У нас будет бездумное копирование условий en-SO с их жёсткими требованиями или своя суверенная демократия? Когда выборы? Минимальная явка? Борьба с фальсификациями и каруселями? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: очень много вопросов. Я за жесткие требования и против «нашего особого пути». Выборы когда готовы будем. Про механику подсчета голосов есть статьи целые.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, одним вопросом: хочу в модераторы, что делать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: начните модерировать прямо сейчас и не останавливайтесь до выборов. Потом выдвигайте свою кандидатуру (и продолжайте модерировать).

Comment: @NickVolynkin насколько я понял по ссылкам - мне надо в основном (<зачёркнуто>стучать</зачёркнуто>) тревоги поднимать по поводу вопросов/ответов? Или достаточно в очереди проверок трудится?

Comment: И вот, теперь ТС модератор :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В настоящее время на StackOverflow и всех остальных сайтах сети действуют следующие правила (оригинал и свободный перевод с английского):

> On Stack Exchange, we believe the core moderators should come from the community, and be elected by the community itself through popular vote. We hold regular elections to determine who these community moderators will be.

Мы в Stack Exchange ([или StackOverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1312/181472)) считаем, что модераторами должны становиться участники сообщества, избранные самим соооществом путем голосования. Мы регулярно организуем выборы, чтобы определить состав модераторов каждого сообщества.

> Community moderators are accorded the highest level of privilege on our community, and should themselves be exemplars of positive behavior and leaders within the community.

Модераторы сообщества получают наивысший уровень привилегий и должны сами быть примерами правильного поведения и лидерами в своём сообществе.

> Our general criteria for moderators are as
>
> - patient and fair
> - leads by example
> - respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words
> - open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track and resolve (hopefully) uncommon disputes and exceptions

Вот наши основные требования к модераторам:

- терпеливый и честный
- вдохновляет других своим примером
- уважает других участников сообщества, что проявляется в поступках и в словах
- готов заниматься модерацией, чтобы поддерживать сообщество в нужном русле и разрешать нечастые (хотелось бы надеяться) споры и исключительные ситуации.

*(дальше специфические требования для сайта, но они тоже использовались для выборов на всех сайтах сети без исключений)*

> For the Stack Overflow election, an eligible candidate for the election must have all of the following badges:
>
> - Civic Duty
> - Strunk & White
> - Deputy
> - Convention

Каждый кандидат в модераторы Stack Overflow должен обладать всеми нижеперечисленными знаками:

- [Гражданский долг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) (Civic Duty)
- [Редактор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) (Strunk & White)
- [Участковый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy) (Deputy)
- [Делегат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/68/convention) (Convention)

*Вот запросы по SEDE, находящие всех потенциальных кандидатов, имеющих все четыре знака на основном сайте: [от PashaPash](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/368679/moderator-election-score-for-all-eligible-candidates-with-score-1?MinRep=300) и [от Nofate](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/368677/moderator-election-score-for-all-eligible-candidates-with-score-1?MinRep=300).*

Comment: ОК, спасибо. Резюмирую: 300 голосов за сообщения других участников на ru-SO, отредактировать 80 сообщений других участников на ru-SO, Отметить 80 сообщений полезными тревогами на ru-SO, 10 сообщений на meta.ru-SO с рейтингом 2 балла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это только необходимые, но далеко не достаточные.

Comment: Ну вот... Все 4 бэйджа из конца ответа собрал, а в списках в последних ссылках меня нема(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб данные SEDE обновляются примерно раз в неделю.

Comment: А-а-а, ладно подожду)

Comment: *"Модераторы сообщества получают наивысший уровень привилегий"* — Вообще-то не наивысший. ;) *"Вот запросы по SEDE, находящие всех потенциальных кандидатов"* — Вообще-то не всех, там нет меня (на момент дампа у меня 1 репа из-за бана) и двух текущих временных модераторов (я так понимаю, им не запретят участвовать из-за формальностей со значками).

Comment: @Discord. Редактируйте! Кстати, это же перевод, так что ошибка и в оригинальном тексте.

Comment: @Discord: а на момент дампа вы наверняка и не были потенциальным кандидатом, т.к. бан )

Comment: @NickVolynkin а `помощник` - это участковый? я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @PauloBerezini спасибо, что заметили. Поправил тут и в https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2025/181472