# Каковы обязательные требования для кандидата в модераторы?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Собственно, скоро выборы, так что хотелось бы узнать, каковы обязателтьные требования к кандидатам. В соседней теме только про рейтинг 300 говорится, но помню, что где-то было обсуждение на тему четырёх знаков. Что всё-таки надо-то?

---

В данный момент есть два аналогичных вопроса, данные в которых противоречивы:

- [Каким критериям должен соответствовать участник сообщества для избрания в модераторы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1398/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)
  И [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1404/178988) на него [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin) 26 сентября, в котором перечисляются 4 награды.
- [Что такое выборы в модераторы сообщества и как они работают?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1983/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82)
  И [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1984/178988) на него [@Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) 11 декабря, где говорится, что никаких требований помимо 300 баллов репутации нет.

Так какие именно требования являются обязательными?
У меня, например, 80 тревог нет, остальное всё есть. Думаю, не только у меня так.

Прошу дать однозначный ответ, а не закрывать вопрос как дубликат одного из этих двух.

Comment: А что за соседняя тема про рейтинг 300?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1984/178988 "Любой участник может выдвинуть свою кандидатуру на пост модератора, с условием удовлетворения условий описанных ниже." И условия только про 300 и ничего про награды.

Comment: @Qwertiy: а, точно. Ну, 300 репутации это необходимое требование, но я не считаю его достаточным. Судя по всему, администрация сайта не выдвигает более строгих требований. Хотя я бы хотел получить подробный ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: Да, хотелось бы однозначности в этом вопросе.

Comment: однозначный ответ - это ответ от администрации в лице Николаса? ответ @NickVolynkin более чем однозначен - нужны 4 беджа. почему про них вырезано упоминание в переводе http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/248633 - загадка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ в чате от @Nofate ♦:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26143188#26143188

> @Nofate можешь точно сказать, обязательны тревоги или нет?

> @Qwertiy в формальных требованиях не указаны

Answer (score 13):

### Однозначный ответ

Вышеупомянутые знаки демонстрируют, что участник имеет хотя бы какой-то опыт в модерации сайта. **Если какой-то участник не имеет хотя бы одного из них, то я однозначно не рассматриваю его в качестве кандидата в модераторы сайта.** Моё мнение не зависит от выдвигаемых администрацией требований и основывается на личном опыте.

Читатель, если вы поддерживаете моё неофициальное требование, предлагаю вам голосовать за ответ. Не поддерживаете — голосовать против.

### Объясняю подробно:

- [Гражданский долг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) (Civic Duty). 80 голосов за вопросы или ответы это совсем элементарное требование. Нужно вовсе не интересоваться сайтом, чтобы не проголосовать 80 раз.
- [Редактор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) (Strunk & White). Правки — не самая увлекательная деятельность на сайте, за них (почти) не дают репутации, очень редко автор исправленного сообщения вас благодарит. Но это необходимая работа для того, кто берет на себя ответственность за сайт.
- [Участковый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy) (Deputy). Тревоги — система обработки исключительных ситуаций на сайте. Тревоги обеспечивают следование правилам. Если участник не имеет опыта  или сознательно воздерживается от использования тревог, то ему будет крайне сложно модерировать сайт. Существенная часть работы модератора — разгребание тревог. Причем модераторам достаются самые непростые случаи, в то время как большинство обрабатывается сообществом. (Спросите у Nofate, как его отправляли читать Второзаконие.)
- [Делегат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/68/convention) (Convention). 10 сообщений на Мете с 2+ баллов. Я считаю, что Мета — это основной инструмент модератора. Он должен уметь обращаться к сообществу, анализировать его работу в целом и влиять на «большие» процессы. Хорошая инструкция или призыв к действию умножаются на усилия десятков активных участников, что всегда больше, чем усилия одного модератора, пусть даже он будет модерировать круглосуточно.

Выдвижение кандидатов закончится 21 декабря. К этой дате можно успеть получить все необходимые знаки (и опыт модерации) даже участнику, который зарегистрировался сегодня.

Comment: Про "делегата" довольно спорно. У самого достаточно богатый опыт как модераторства, так и управления оными. Наиболее грамотные и адекватные модераторы всегда выходили из молчаливых флегм, которые тихо, но верно "работу работают"

Answer (score 10):

Предлагаю не зацикливаться на формальностях.

Что такое требование по репутации? Даже до окончания беты 300 репы не давало доступ к очереди проверок: нужно было 350 для первых-поздних, 500 для закрытия-открытия. То есть пользователь с 300 репутации даже не знает, как полноценно пользоваться модераторскими инструментами, доступными для юзеров. Может ли такой пользователь рассчитывать на поддержку избирателями? Вряд ли.

Что такое требование по значкам? Это доказательство того, что пользователь хотя бы в минимальном объёме использует модераторские инструменты и хоть как-то участвует в жизни сообщества. Всего-то надо:

- поднять 80 тревог;
- отредактировать 80 сообщений;
- проголосовать 300 раз;
- разместить заплюсованный пост на Мете.

Может ли пользователь, который не следит за наполнением сайта, не исправляет сообщения, не голосует и не обсуждает проблемы на Мете, рассчитывать на поддержку избирателями? Вряд ли.

Хоть жёсткое требование будет на репу и значки, хоть мягкое — суть не изменится. У нас есть 10 активных пользователей, которые имеют больше 1500 репутации, все необходимые значки и ещё минимум десяток в придачу. Может ли новичок с сотней репы и без значков соревноваться с ними? Соревноваться — может, победить — вряд ли.

P. S. Если вас интересует возможность выдвижения своей кандидатуры, то выдвинуться, думаю, вам никто не помешает. Однако 50 тревог, 150 правок, 1000 однобоких голосов за всё время существования сайта и прочие признаки говорят не в вашу пользу. Вы ценитель не качества, а количества, а для модератора это критично. Впрочем, это лишь моё мнение.

P. P. S. Вам что-то мешает поднять 30 дополнительных тревог, чтобы обеспечить себе право на выдвижение? Это число за день выбивается без особого напряжения.

Comment: Во-первых, у меня дневной лимит меньше 20, во-вторых, это не логично намеренно накидывать тревог ради значка...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну так за два дня управитесь, значит. В смысле "намеренно"? На сайте есть множество проблем, вопрос только в поиске. У меня вон 1235 тревог, и это даже не рекорд.

Comment: Я постоянно отмечают вопросы флагами, но почему-то в профиле всего 9 принятых тревог. Хотя я точно знаю, что принятых флагов у меня больше сотни. Или флаги и тревоги - разные вещи?

Comment: @Discord а мне показывает в вашем профиле "6 полезных тревог".

Comment: @Suvitruf Вы смотрите профиль на Мете. Перейдите на основной сайт.

Comment: @Discord хорошо. В чём различие тревог и флагов? Функционально одно и то же. Но почему-то я вижу всего "9 принятых тревог", хотя помечал флагами успешным в десятки раз больше, я уверен.

Comment: @Suvitruf Чтобы посмотреть свою статистику по тревогам, нажмите на ссылку со счётчиком тревог у себя в профиле. Счётчик отображает число полезных минус число бесполезных и игнорирует спорные. / Флаги и тревоги — одно и то же. Если где-то на нашем сайте встречается "флаг", то это баг.

Comment: @Discord я имел ввиду, что в каждом вопросе есть две кнопки "закрыть" и "тревога". Это одно  и то же?

Comment: @Suvitruf Нет. При маленькой репе "рекомендация закрытия" происходит через тревоги, после получения доступа к голосованию за закрытие тревоги и закрытия становятся полностью отдельными (ну, из диалога тревоги можно перейти в диалог закрытия; при этом счётчик доступных операций внизу диалога меняется соответственно).

Comment: @Discord так какую из кнопок мне жать? Так как голоса к закрытию в списке тревог не учитываются...

Comment: @Suvitruf Вы должны выбирать тот пункт, который соответствует сути вашей претензии к содержанию поста. А система зачтёт соответственно.

Comment: @Discord так там внутри пункты практически одни и те же. Зачем тогда две кнопки, если они делают одно и то же?

Answer (score 2):

Надо понимать, что модератор - это не рыцарь в белых доспехах, сеющий добро и заставляющий девичьи сердца учащенно биться. Модератор - это помесь сантехника альтруиста с ассенизатором.

Ему совершенно не обязательно быть ниндзя `soft skills` и гуру в каком либо направлении ИТ. Все, что ему нужно (это я вынес из своего обширного опыта как модерирования, так и управления оными) - это быть флегматичным слоном с обостренным чувством справедливости, очень желательно педантом и альтруистом.

И если с медалькой за "Гражданский долг" я еще могу с оговорками согласиться, то "Помощник" и "Делегат" - это вообще мимо модератора, от слова совсем.

Comment: Помощник - совсем не мимо.  Как вы собираетесь разгребать чужие тревоги, если не поставили хотя бы сотню своих?

Comment: @PashaPash это мне напоминает боян про педиатра "Как же она будет лечить детей, если у нее самой детей нет!?". Бить тревогу и разбираться с тревожными сообщениями - это две активности не связанные ничем кроме объекта действия

Comment: вы вот шутите, но есть такой "замечательный" педиатр Доктор Спок. Он был так себе отцом (достаточно жестоким), его жена  практически отстранила его от воспитания детей. И он точно никогда не кормил детей грудью. Что не помешало ему понаписывать в своей книге строгие рекомендации "кормить не чаще чем раз в три часа! на руки не брать! Дети должны спать строго на груди!". Это стоило тысячам человек кучу нервов, тысячам детей - часов голодного плача, а тем, кто начал укладывать ребенка на грудь - наверняка еще и пары десятков смертей СВДС.

Comment: Так что предлагаю откинуть вашу абстракцию как дырявую и изначально неверную. Модератор не должен никого лечить. На SO своеобразная система тревог. У меня тоже обширный опыт модерации (не только на SO), так что я знаю о чем говорю. Модератор должен понимать, какая тревога требует его вмешательства, а какая - нет. Нужно понимать, чем руководствовался тот, кто ставил тревогу. Иначе модер просто начнет сносить те ответы, которые ему кажутся технически неверными и удалять ответы за знак вопроса в них. Это достаточно сильно отличается от "просто зови модератора, пусть он думает" на обычных форумах.

Comment: @PashaPash там в продолжение был закономерный вопрос "Как же этот онколог будет рак лечить, если сам им не болел?", ну да ладно. То, что вы описали ни коем образом не связано с количеством поданных человеком тревог. Среагировать на "отклонение от нормы" и проанализировать и произвести корректирующее воздействие -
 это два совершенно разных скила.

Comment: это один и тот же скилл. критерии для обнаружения "о, в этом сообщении есть отклонение от нормы" те же самые, которыми модератор пользуется при оценке "да, это отклонение от нормы". Т.е. модератор обычно не выбирает корректирующее действие. Он просто подтверждает "да, отклонение было, и именно такое".

Comment: ну ок, для вас это два разных скилла. для меня - один. возможно, вы как-то по-другому подходите к просмотру очередей. тем не менее, для меня эти скиллы неразделимы, так что лично я считаю Помощник действительно необходимым беджиком.

Comment: @PashaPash разбор очереди - это конвейер. Тут, в первую очередь, нужна усидчивость, стрессоустойчивость и понимание того, что ты делаешь. Медалька "Помощник", в большинстве случаев, - это результат лихой кавалерийской атаки по тылам противника. Бей всех - на небесах разберутся. В профиле высветилось "рекомендуем следующей медалькой Помощник" и понеслась охота.

Comment: модераторская очередь - не настолько конвейер, как обычные очереди проверки :) насчет охоты - постановка тревог на все подряд вызовет бан для кнопки тревоги - т.е. нельзя просто так взять и поставить кучу тревог. Медальку Помощник (Участковый) достаточно тяжело взять наскоком. Точнее, можно, но это очень заметно модераторам - и за последний год таких наскакивающих было всего пара человек.

Comment: @PashaPash, знаки за тревоги вполне можно насобирать специально. Берём подходящую очередь проверок, просматриваем, а там, где согласны, открываем вопрос в соседней вкладке и ставим на него очередную тревогу того же вида.