# Выборы модератора сообщества 2015

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

В настоящее время проводятся выборы модераторов сообщества 2015!
Выборы модераторов сообщества состоят из трех этапов:

1. Этап выдвижения кандидатур
2. Этап предварительных выборов
3. Этап выборов

Обычно процесс выборов занимает от 2 до 3 недель, но все зависит от количества кандидатов.

Пожалуйста, посетите официальную страницу выборов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election для получения дополнительной информации и принимайте участие!

Если у Вас есть вопросы по процессу проведения выборов или по кандидатам в модераторы, задавайте их здесь, на Мете — только убедитесь, что ваши вопросы имеют метку [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).

Подробнее о выборах модераторов:

- [Что такое выборы в модераторы сообщества и как они работают?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1983/)
- [Каковы обязательные требования для кандидата в модераторы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1998/)
- [Каким критериям должен соответствовать участник сообщества для избрания в модераторы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1398/)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Желаю удачи всем кандидатам!