# Почему у нас только два констебля?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, модерация

Во время беты ведь было 3 модератора, а знак [Констебль](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/85/constable) получили только двое. Почему?

Comment: Николас - не модератор. Он сотрудник компании.

Comment: @PashaPash ему нормальными деньгами платят за работу, знаки не нужны. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Модераторы, как мы знаем, призваны служить «мостом» соединяющим компанию и сообщество. У моста, в нашем случае, есть две стороны. Со стороны сообщества – [это участники выбранные большинством по результатам голосования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2044/), со стороны компании – [сотрудники выбранные компанией](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/welcome-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-stack-overflow-in-russian/).

Как упоминается в комментариях, признаюсь, с какого-то момента я являюсь сотрудником Stack Overflow, то есть я модератор от компании и знак, на сколько я понимаю, мне не положен.