# Констебль jmac?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, знаки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/85/constable

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто это и почему он в этом списке?

Comment: Твинк Чабановского? :) Наверное, дело в том, что этот jmac является КМ для SE судя по [общей анкете](https://stackexchange.com/users/2184621/jmac?tab=accounts)(*Community Manager for Stack Exchange since July 2014*) и, возможно, действительно где-то там числился как куратор в процессе переноса hashcode.ru под крылышко Stack Exchange. Лучше, наверное узнать у действующего КМ, или может оставшуюся парочку со криншота распросить. Вряд ли это дефект миграции, хотя, кто знает.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я просто не припомню, чтоб он раньше был в этом списке.

Comment: В общем, уже было в чате [упоминание](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=43768114#43768114) об этом. Однозначного ответа, правда, нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно [старому ответу Николая](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2264/176217), знак «Констебль» не должен бы выдаваться сотрудникам компании:

> то есть я модератор от компании и знак, на сколько я понимаю, мне не положен

<sup>* Орфография и пунктуация автора сохранены.</sup>

Ранее я предположил в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8823/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C-jmac?noredirect=1#comment36182_8823), что дело скорее всего именно в статусе сотрудника, упомянутого участника из Японии:

> Наверное, дело в том, что этот jmac является КМ для SE судя по [общей анкете](https://stackexchange.com/users/2184621/jmac?tab=accounts) (Community Manager for Stack Exchange since July 2014) и, возможно, действительно где-то там числился как куратор в процессе переноса hashcode.ru под крылышко Stack Exchange. Лучше, наверное узнать у действующего КМ, или может оставшуюся парочку со криншота распросить. Вряд ли это дефект миграции, хотя, кто знает.

Таким образом, скорее всего, знак надо бы сдать в центральное знакохранилище. Правда, учитывая, другие существующие дефекты, типа [незаслуженной репутации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291897/339911), вряд ли что-то будет предпринято.