# Перевод Topic в контексте документации

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Не так давно [было объявлено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/) о новом разделе на Stack Overflow — «документации». Разработка движется полным ходом, как результат, на Transifex появляется множество новых строк.

[Вот выборка этих строк на Transifex.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/52564855?translated=no&q=topic)

Какой наиболее подходящий перевод для «Topic» в контексте документации?

Comment: Похоже, часть строк уже перевели с «темой»: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/56878537?translated=yes&q=topic

Comment: Переведены, но не подтверждены!

Answer (score 2):

#### Раздел

«Раздел документации» или «раздел справочной документации».

Минусы:

- Тоже можно принять за глагол, особенно если на дворе весна.

Answer (score 1):

#### Тема

Минусы:

- Вообще непонятно, что это такое «тема документации».

Answer (score 1):

#### Статья

"Документация по регулярным выражениям, статья про разбор HTML."

Answer (score 0):

#### Публикация

Минусы:

- Получится, что публикация это и действие (публикация вопроса или ответа) и тип сообщения.