# Первооткрыватели документации: ответы на ваши вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, документация

Обновление.

[Проект «Документация» был закрыт](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation).

---

Свободный перевод публикации «[Warlords of Documentation: Your Quest(ions Answered)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/)».

---

Несколько недель назад на Мете было [опубликовано предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/) по расширению Stack Overflow – создать раздел «Документация». Мы получили обнадеживающий отзыв: более 2,400+ голосов «за» и большое количество заявок на участие в бете.

Вы задали огромное количество вопросов, многие из которых мы активно обсуждали еще до анонса, но далеко не на все у нас есть ответы (например, еще не все ясно с версиями). Было много и таких вопросов, о которых мы даже не задумывались. Взять хотя бы само название «документация». Мы коснулись некоторых вопросов в [последнем подкасте](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/stack-exchange-podcast-68-a-badger-a-horse-and-a-dik-dik-the-documentation-episode/) и еще больше коснемся сегодня.

Еще раз хотел бы подчеркнуть, насколько важны ваши отзывы для создания чего-либо по-настоящему работающего. **Большое вам спасибо!**

### Теперь вопросы!

Позволю себе повториться: ***все обсуждаемое в данной публикации находится в очень сыром виде и может измениться в любой момент***. Пожалуйста, не воспринимайте ничего из написанного как стабильный функционал: после получения отзывов от вас мы внесем изменения в подсистему, а также сделаем это еще и еще, наблюдая, как «реальные люди» делают «реальные вещи».

#### Что ожидается от «документации»?

Отчасти мы дали ответ на этот вопрос в явной форме несколько раз во время обсуждения того, приветствуются ли руководства (tutorials), являются ли примеры «целью» и хотим ли мы переработать справочную документацию.

Мы считаем, что в документацию входит следующее:

- Небольшие страницы со «связанными задачами» для классов, модулей и так далее.

  - Например, «Типичные ошибки при использовании `Dictionary<T, V>`» вполне могут подойти.
- Странички о различных наиболее важных особенностях и нюансах.

  - Например, использование [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) может быть достаточно запутано, чтобы создать для него специальную страничку, но, с другой стороны, создавать отдельную страницу для `Dictionary<T, V>.ToString()` не стоит.
- Короткий (одностраничный) материал, похожий на руководство использования.

  - Например, что-то вроде «Вводного экскурса в...» или «Как правильно осуществлять HTTP-запросы».

Не удивлюсь, если многое изменится так же, как и в случае «тематики» для сайта вопросов и ответов.

#### Имеет ли новый функционал сайта точки соприкосновения с официальной документацией?

В первую очередь хотелось бы подчеркнуть, что мы не планируем воображать документацию на Stack Overflow как «официальную». Мы относимся к ней так же, как и к сайту вопросов и ответов: пополняемую и модерируемую исключительно сообществом, даже в случае если правообладатели дали «благословение» на ее ведение на нашем сайте (например, как было со многими продуктами Google).

Существует несколько аспектов официальной документации, которые, как мы считаем, не стоит дублировать. Например, исчерпывающие списки классов, методов, полей и т. д. В  основном это вещи, не требующие поддержки живым человеком или создаваемые автоматически.

#### Как мы предотвратим появление неконструктивной документации?

За счет предупреждения двух «болезней»: возникновения города-призрака и нежелательного поведения – «дублирования документации с исключительной целью получения репутации».

Мы планируем достичь этого за счет цикла «кто-то запросил эту документацию» -> «эта документация была полезна кому-то» и понимания, что репутации тесно коррелирует с этим циклом. Просто опубликовать документацию или отредактировать ее с целью получения репутации будет невозможно.

Реализация будет сводиться к тесной связке запроса, отзывов и совместному взаимодействию ([первые две вкладки на макете панели](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDmik.png)). В дополнение,мы планируем добавить систему для проверки<sup>*</sup> изменений до того, как они появятся на сайте (третья вкладка на макете), таким образом участнику будет необходимо убедить несколько коллег в том, что документация конструктивная.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Пока что мы еще не можем понять, кто (если вообще кто-либо) сможет избегать проверки. Конечно же, имеет смысл дать возможность пропустить проверку проверенным участникам. Мы планируем работать над этим вопросом в течение ближайшего месяца.</sub>

#### Что мы будем делать с дроблением?

[Это опасение получило наибольшее количество голосов «за»](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303867/80572). Ответ основывается на заданных в сообщении вопросах.

Во-первых, необходимо понять разницу между «полезным» и «вредным» дроблениями. (Я использую термин «дробление» для обозначения «связанного содержимого, разнесенного на различные домены, в различные системы и т. д.».)

«Вредное» дробление будет в случае, когда вам для получения *той же* информации, как и раньше, приходится воспользоваться несколькими ресурсами. Как если бы, к примеру, Oracle решила бы разделить документацию по Java напополам и разместить ее на разных доменах, используя разные стили форматирования и разную структуру, – это было бы вредное дробление. Аналогично если бы новый раздел документации внес бы лишь необходимость искать одну и ту же информацию одного качества как на MSDN, так и на Stack Overflow, которую вы раньше могли найти на MSDN, это было бы вредным дроблением.

«Полезное» дробление возникает в том случае, если информации становится больше либо повышается ее качество в сравнении с тем, что было ранее. Существует множество примеров полезного дробления, например, блоги разработчиков, публикации, примеры, кода на Github, подкасты и руководства на YouTube. Более того, можно утверждать, что документация в стиле javadocs есть пример полезного дробления, в конце концов всю информацию вы и так могли бы найти в исходном коде. Если создаваемая документация будет более полезна и качественней той, что существует сейчас, дробление будет оправдано.

Каким же образом мы предотвратим вредное дробление? В два шага.

Во-первых, постараемся отговорить от вредного дробления и затем будем бороться с тем, что проскользнет.

Здесь ключевой момент заключается в том, что именно сообщество определяет, какой документации быть. Если большинство людей удовлетворено текущей проектной документацией, запросы просто не будут появляться, как не будет и тех, кто ее напишет или воспользуется ей, то есть новая система будет пуста. Право принимать решение о том, имеет ли какая-либо документация право существовать в Интернете в руках сообщества (по аналогии с вопросами, ответами, метками). Структура системы репутации, вознаграждающей за документацию, служит вторым фильтром, так как люди будут склонны к концентрации усилий на создание недостающих знаний.

Чтобы блокировать просочившееся плохое содержимое, мы добавим систему голосования и тревог, что придаст надежности примерам и самим публикациям. Для этого мы с первого дня закладываем понятие «необходимо обратить внимание на» активность ([макет вкладки «необходимо улучшить»](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDmik.png), честно говоря, пока мы не довольны именем). Вкладка будет содержать больше, чем просто ожидающее проверки «плохое дробление», в нее также будет попадать информация низкого качества, информация вида скопировал/вставил, более недействительная информация, спам и так далее.

Немного в сторону. Мы считаем, что Stack Overflow прекрасный пример «полезного» дробления. Вопросы по программированию как существовали до Stack Overflow, так и существуют сейчас, но мы в любом случае сделали Интернет чуть-чуть лучше. Надеюсь, вместе мы сможем улучшить его снова документацией.

#### Как будут работать версии?

Этот вопрос был задан много раз, и нам кристально ясно, что к моменту запуска очень важно найти хорошее решение. В момент публикации предыдущего анонса у нас были лишь планы. Сегодня мы уже можем продемонстрировать *небольшой* прогресс.

Суть в том, что каждая метка, которая имеет связанную с ней документацию, будет иметь список версий по ней. Каждая страница документации может иметь часть этого списка, который будет ассоциироваться с ней. К конкретной версии может относиться любое количество блоков информации, представленных на странице. В случае появления новой версии, мы *предполагаем*, что старая все еще будет поддерживаться. Мы будем использовать эту информацию как в случае отображения, так и в случае поиска.

Несколько прототипов, как все это может выглядеть

[image: Назначение версий при редактировании]
<sub>Отметить всю публикацию целиком как отображаемую по умолчанию для выбранной версии.</sub>

[image: Уровень меток Markdown]
<sub>Что будет отображаться, если вы отметите лишь один блок разметки.</sub>

[image: Отображение версии публикации]
<sub>Мы все еще в процессе работы над отображением множественных версий, но, с большой вероятностью, они будут выглядеть примерно так,  как на рисунке выше.</sub>

#### Что делать с новыми релизами и устаревшим содержимым?

Вопрос тесно связан с версиями.

Короткий ответ: использовать тревоги. Скорее всего, мы добавим причину вроде «это устарело» в панель к остальным тревогам. Также мы экспериментируем с идеями «автоматических отметок в случае появления новых версий», но на данный момент не пришли к чему-то конкретному.

Мы надеемся, что этот функционал мы отточим во время беты.

#### Как насчет добавления иерархий, вложенности, группировки, пространств имен, модулей и так далее?

Этот вопрос также задавался несколько раз и несколько раз получал простой ответ: основной способ поиска документации и навигации в ней – **использования поисковика**.

В качестве примера я подобрал несколько публикаций из MSDN, на которые натыкался в последнее время:

[image: История MSDN]

Вы можете видеть шаблон.

Основываясь на наблюдениях и личном опыте, мы не находим полезным какие-либо строгие иерархии. К тому же наличие подобных структур добавляет множество источников споров и порождает серьезные технические проблемы (например, что случится с публикацией, если изменилась иерархия, кто может ее изменять, каким образом). Другими словами, в нашем понимании, игра не стоит свеч.

Что *самое* важное, так это ссылки. Информация постоянно меняется, и ссылки позволяют оставаться гибкими. Мы решительно намерены использовать ссылки и интеллектуальный подбор «связанных публикаций», основываясь на них.

Скорее всего, мы будем отображать релевантные данные во многих местах, как минимум, в поиске.

[image: Поведение поиска]

Возможно, как и в случае других элементов, мы поймем, что ошибаемся во время беты, но на данный момент мы убеждены, что этот подход довольно многообещающий, для того чтобы попробовать его.

#### Как поступать с различными лицензиями?

Наша цель заключается в том, чтобы кто угодно мог использовать содержимое сайта (вопросы и ответы и документация), добавляя соответствующее указание авторства. На данный момент мы достигаем этого за счет использования лицензии [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Это означает, что любая проектная документация на Stack Overflow может быть свободно воспроизведена в прикладных целях, даже если исходная лицензия самого проекта отличается.

Наша настоящая лицензия подвергалась обсуждениям в прошлом несколько раз. Мы постоянно возвращаемся к вынесенным предложениям в попытках улучшения ситуации, но во всех существующих вариантах есть большие недостатки. Как результат, мы *пока* не нашли ничего лучше текущей лицензии. Информационные технологии опережают закон, к сожалению, но мы все равно активно ищем решение проблемы.

#### Как мы собираемся избежать плагиата?

Этот вопрос тоже поднимался несколько раз, особенно в контексте описания меток.

Описание меток не так заметно, как хотелось бы (это одна из многих проблем данного функционала), что является, по нашему мнению, основной проблемой плагиата в них. Мы постараемся сделать документацию максимально публичной, к примеру, за счет проверки любых изменения до того, как они станут доступными, мы также планируем упросить процесс поднятия тревог для содержимого формата скопировал/вставил. В дополнение мы намерены проводить небольшой вводный курс для тех, кто желает внести вклад в документацию, где расскажем, что плагиат будет удален в любом случае.

#### Где документация будет «жить»?

На самом деле я не задавался этим вопросом всерьез, но, судя по количеству вопросов, должен был.

Документация предполагает создание нового раздела на *сайте*. Устройство навигации все еще находится в процессе обсуждения. На сегодня оправданным, на наш взгляд, шагом является добавление новой кнопки [Документация] между [Вопросы] и [Метки].

Считаем, что такое решение намного более целесообразно, чем создание нового сайта, так как вопросы, ответы и документация дополняют друг друга. Множество вопросов и ответов будут ссылаться на документацию, многие участники, отвечающие на вопросы, будут формировать документацию, да и [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8) работают аналогично секции вопросов и ответов.

К тому же есть несколько технических преимуществ данного подхода, в основном касающихся авторизации и поддержки TLS. Другое преимущество на сегодня заключается в том, что подход нового сайта не позволяет легко расширить документацию на всю сеть Stack Exchange.

#### Правильное ли имя мы подобрали?

Вопрос спорный, так как существует множество вариаций того, что люди считают документацией. Можно ли назвать документацией развернутые статьи на MSDN или http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/? Что если на такие статьи будут ссылаться со страниц описания классов? И так далее. Как минимум для меня такие названия, как руководства (tutorials) и примеры использования (examples), неполны и зачастую лишь обозначают, что *некоторые* типы, возможно, с большой вероятностью, наверное существуют.

В настоящий момент мы придерживаемся названия «Документация» как минимум до начала беты, но, конечно же, **[будем рады вашим предложениям](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1I35fakw7EOhu0p-5YZ_VqXcTWtQ8VEa2DY7TbG_fCyc/viewform)**.

#### Как насчет справочника без соединения с Интернетом?

Вопрос также обсуждался несколько раз. Ответ прост: мы подготовим набор стилей, вся документация будет доступна в виде снимка базы данных и через API.

#### Как насчет устройств с небольшим экраном, например, мобильных телефонов, планшетов и др.?

Мы подготовим мобильную версию для документации с большой вероятностью уже после беты. Документация не будет включена в наше мобильное приложение до тех пор, пока функционал не стабилизируется, в связи с продолжительными циклами публикации новых версий приложения в магазинах.

#### Почему документация сосредоточена исключительно вокруг Stack Overflow, а не остальной Сети?

Создание чего-то сложного *намного* проще в случае концентрации на одной конкретной проблеме. К тому же мы хотим придерживаться как можно более коротких итераций во время беты, как результат, чем меньше вариаций применения, тем лучше.

*Но* это не означает, что мы планируем не расширить документацию на всю Сеть в будущем или планируем не создать ее специализаций для того, чтобы она лучше подходила нуждам других сообществ в будущем.

---

Вот и все! Уверен, у вас появится еще больше вопросов, а у нас ответов, как только мы будем ближе и ближе подходить к моменту запуска закрытой беты. Спешу подчеркнуть еще раз, **спасибо всем, кто опубликовал отзывы**! Пожалуйста, продолжайте в том же духе!

### Вы все еще можете зарегистрироваться на участие в бете

Для вашего участия нам необходимо получить от вас следующее:

- Вашу электронную почту.
- Ссылку на вашу учетную запись Stack Overflow.
- Список из 2-5 [меток](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular), по которым вы бы хотели составлять документацию.

Пожалуйста, выбирайте метки на первых двух страницах раздела [популярные метки](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular), которые имеют особенно активное сообщество пользователей, такие как [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [r](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), or [ios](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). Таким образом мы сможем проверить всю систему в реальных условиях вместе с множеством разработчиков на стадии закрытой беты.

*Вы можете зарегистрироваться вплоть до запуска закрытой беты. На регистрацию нет ограничений ни по текущему вкладу, ни по репутации.*

## [Зарегистрируйтесь и помогите сделать документацию лучше!](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform)

Comment: Некоторое время назад «Документация» [была закрыта](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/2553424). Планируется ли перевод *post mortem*-а по процессу реализации данной инициативы?

Comment: @Arhad Обновил вопрос. Думаю, нет. Я вижу, что у нас в списке на перевод очень много важных статей весят. Вероятно, когда я доберусь до статьи про закрытие, она будет совсем не актуальной.

Answer (score 3):

> Короткий ответ: использовать тревоги. Скорее всего, мы добавим причину вроде «это устарело» в панель к остальным тревогам.

Насколько я представляю, функционал тревог предназначен для удаления, а это не является правильным вариантом. Надо просто отмечать содержимое устаревшим, но не удалять его. Это нужно из-за того, что далеко не все используют последние версии.

Например, около года назад я искал информацию по разработке под IE Quirks 5 - найти что-то было почти нереально. Поисковых результатов по теме почти нет, а попадающиеся ссылки по большей части битые.

Посмотрите, как [делают на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XDomainRequest) и сделайте так же - большое красное предупреждение об устаревании, выделение серым (вместо чёрного) в списке и явная информация о версиях.

Comment: Не будут удалять. Просто документация, как написано, по умолчанию считается подходящей и для новой версии. А это не всегда правда. Вот для отметки таких breaking changes и нужна тревога.