# Есть ли место, которое организовано в виде учебника по заданной теме?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Сообщество SO собирает базу лучших знаний, актуальных и качественных. Удобно было бы получить некий учебник по выбранной теме, сформированный из ответов сообщества.

Идея кажется настолько очевидной, что думаю, что такое решение уже есть. Где его найти?

Если же такого решения еще нет, то можно расценивать данный пост, как предложение по созданию таких учебников.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть Документация StackOverflow, новая фича, которая сейчас находится в стадии закрытого тестирования на En.SO. Когда-нибудь это появится и у нас.

Там как раз будут примеры, сформированные из ответов сообщества.

- [Первооткрыватели документации: предложение расширения Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1247/181472)
- [Первооткрыватели документации: ответы на ваши вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1390/181472)