# Создание свода актуальных решений Меты

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Как известно, многие важные решения принимаются сообществом на Мете. В тоже время очень многие пользователи совершенно не в курсе этих решений.
Этому во многом способствуют следующие факторы:

- Разрозненность информации, которая размещена в различных топиках;
- Многие ныне действующие решения были приняты давно и топики с ними также давно успели "утонуть" под "натиском" новых обсуждений.

В результате, даже при всём желании, важную информацию становится очень тяжело найти.

Предлагаю создать своего рода свод актуальных решений Меты, в котором будут собраны все решения, действующие в данный момент, и разместить его на сайте на видном месте.

Дело в том, что большинство адекватных пользователей, как правило, читает подобные вещи и старается их придерживаться.

Безусловно, создание такого свода и поддержание его актуальности требует определённых усилий. Но это гораздо лучше, чем многократное проведение модераторами или просто опытными пользователями разъяснительной работы относительно одних и тех же моментов после возникновения очередного прецедента.

Хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества по данному вопросу.

Comment: А что, механизм *принятия решений на Мете* реально уже существует?

Comment: @avp на чем зеленый чекбокс - то и решение! :)

Comment: @PashaPash, это сильно.

Comment: @avp это печально :(

Answer (score 7):

Правила сайта отражены в Справке.

Когда мы что-то решаем, нужно просто дорабатывать соответствующий раздел справки, или писать новый. Так уже было, механизм рабочий.

Если должны измениться конкретные инструкции, то нужно поменять строки в интерфейсе сайта.

Можно делать регулярный вестник Меты — раз в пару недель публиковать короткий пост, в нем несколько самых важных обсуждений — не только ссылки, а суть вопроса в трех строках. И пришпиливать его меткой [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) до выхода следующего вестника.

Для организации других важных вопросов можно использовать метку [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) и вопрос «[Часто задаваемые вопросы о Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/983/181472)»

Comment: Справка не резиновая. В нее нельзя запихнуть все. Кроме того, некоторые решения без детального обоснования могут вызвать внутренее сопротивление. Например, просто написать "нельзя закрывать работу за автора" недостаточно.

Comment: соглашусь с @PashaPash: *Все в справке не напишешь* , идея на **важные** решения/обсуждения вешать метку, не обязательно **важное**, любую другую но которая будет обозначать только это, т.е. что в данной теме обсуждается/решается проблема, а в справке сделать пометку что посты на мете с такой меткой *рекомендуются* к ознакомлению(как минимум). Если данное решение перестает быть актуальным убираем данную метку.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @NickVolynkin – справка на то и нужна, чтобы содержать основные правила. Правила формируются на основе коллективного решения. Если какие-то обсуждения не попадают в справку по тем или иным причинам, то следует отмечать такие вопросы метками [tag:faq], [tag:справка] и [tag:обсуждение], либо ввести другую мету специально для этих целей.

Answer (score 5):

Далеко не все решения заслуживают доведения до широких масс. Необходимость знать все правила во всех нюансах, актуальные события и прочее есть только у избираемых модераторов, а также пользователей, очень активно модерирующих сайт с использованием привилегий за высокую репутацию.

`<лирическое-отступление>` Скажем, вы приходите в магазин, чтобы купить колбасу. Вы обижаетесь, что кассир не рассказывает вам про процесс открытия и закрытия кассовой смены, что бухгалтер не читает лекции про статьи дохода и расхода, что уборщица не учит оттирать въевшиеся пятна и так далее? Нет, вам неинтересно происходящее в служебных помещениях магазина, вы не хотите вникать во все внутренние процессы, вы просто хотите купить колбасу.

Вот и Мета — это служебные помещения магазина. Никто не будет заставлять вас вникать во все детали, но никто и не будет запрещать вам пойти и устроиться в магазин. Интересуетесь процессом — покажите это, а не ожидайте, что все работники будут расказывать всем покупателям про внутренние дела.`</лирическое-отступление>`

**Пример №1**: если сообщество приняло решение удалить метку, то это интересно только для тех, кто занимается сжиганием меток. Они могут подписаться на соответствующую метку на Мете и следить за новостями.

**Пример №2**: если сообщество решило не уничтожать все "учебные задания", а обращать внимание на качество, то это лишь *уточнение* и *пояснение* существующих правил (учебные задания на самом деле никогда не были запрещены). Эту информацию следует довести только до тех, кто активно и без разбора закрывает вопросы с учебными заданиями, то есть неверно интерпретирует существующие правила. Это могут сделать модераторы в индивидуальном порядке. Если это явление массовое, то можно воспользоваться меткой "важное".

**Пример №3**: если сообщество решило улучшить, исправить или изменить перевод какой-то строки в интерфейсе сайта, то эта информация важна только для пользователей Transifex, имеющих доступ к редактированию перевода сайта, а также администрации, которая имеет доступ к редактированию справки. Широкие массы только увидят улучшенный текст, им об этом знать не надо.

**Пример №4**: если сообщество собирает вопросы для кандидатов на выборах модераторов, то важно услышать вопросы многих активных пользователей. В этом случае модератор может пометить вопрос на Мете как "важное", и ссылка на вопрос появится в блоке справа.

**Пример №5**: если сообщество принимает решение разрешить вопросы жанра Server Fault, то это изменение правил, и оно отражается на соответствующей странице справки.

В целом, существующих инструментов вполне достаточно, а в большинстве случаев необходимости трубить на весь мир обо всём происходящем на Мете нет никакой нужды. Большинство решений можно считать служебными, а потому бесполезными для большинства посетителей Stack Overflow.

Если вы хотите принять более активное участие — вам всегда рады. Регулярно заходите на Мету, участвуйте в обсуждениях, голосуйте, подписывайтесь на интересные метки, на подписки — всё, как на основном сайте. Но не надо заставлять остальных, кому это неинтересно, заниматься тем же самым. Каждому своё.

Comment: 1. *Далеко не все решения заслуживают доведения до широких масс.* - прочитал, перечитал смысл выше написанного понял так: Есть элита и есть *серая масса*. Даже если у меня(читать большая часть пользователей) нет особых привилегий, то обсуждать/знать о принятых решениях я бы хотел. 2. *Это могут сделать модераторы в индивидуальном порядке.* - тут у меня возникает только один вопрос зачем Вы тянете покрывало на себя? Так ведь можно и надорваться. P.S.: все выше сказанное IMHO, если кого то обидел то прошу прощения

Comment: @Bald56rus Есть те, кому *есть дело до сайта*, и те, кому *нет дела да сайта*. Статистика такова, что подавляющему большинству посетителей интересны ответы на их программистские вопросы, а не тонкие нюансы процесса появления этих вопросов на сайте. Откуда вы взяли "серые массы"? Суть моего ответа в том, что никто никого не будет зставлять читать Мету, это бесполезно. Если же вы хотите её читать — добро пожаловать, регулярно заходите на Мету, участвуйте в обсуждениях, голосуйте, подписывайтесь на интересные метки, на подписки — всё, как на основном сайте.

Comment: @Bald56rus Обновил ответ. Думаю, теперь "ярлыки" в этой дихотомии более ясны. / Что касается уведомления пользователей о нарушении правил, то это действительно прямая обязанность модераторов. Если вы хотите принять участие, то можете отправить тревогу. Ну или написать комментарий к любому посту юзера, если модератора сейчас нет на сайте (я так иногда делал). Тянуть на себя одеяло я не могу, потому что я здесь не модератор, и никогда им не был. :)

Comment: Я знаю что Вы не модератор :) Я хочу получить список действующих/актуальных решений принятых здесь на мете(даже если я не смогу им следовать). Новые я стараюсь посещать/участвовать, но просматривать все темы для их поиска, блин, честно мне лень но это не значит что я не хочу быть в их курсе. а вот если бы в справке было написано: *Темы на мете с такой меткой обозначают решения принятые сообществом касательного *внутренней кухни*, всем было бы намного проще, и модераторам и остальным пользователям.

Comment: @Bald56rus Определитесь, какая часть кухни вас интересует. Посмотрите список меток, подпишитесь на интересующие. Вероятно, стоит начать с просмотра топа вопросов по метке "обсуждение" с принятыми заплюсованными ответами.

Comment: Спасибо, а если бы это где то было написано то согласитесь все было бы намного проще/прозрачнее для *новичков*

Answer (score 3):

> Дело в том, что большинство адекватных пользователей, как правило
>   читает подобные вещи и старается их придерживаться.

Я считаю себя относительно адекватным, но подобными вещами особо никогда не интересовался раньше.

Идея, конечно, интересная, вчера в чатике обсуждали. Проблема с этим сводом будет точно такая же, как и с текущими правила - большинство людей не будет их читать.

Поэтому надо как-то улучшить механизм, который бы вовлекал людей во все эти вещи. Ведь важно не только то, чтоб люди ознакомились с этими обсуждениями, но и сами в них участвовали.

Answer (score 3):

Поддерживаю.

Можно создать отдельную тему, в которой будут перечислены ссылки на вопросы, где обсуждались долгосрочные решения. Типа уточнения тематики (например, вопросов по домашним заданиям, настройке ОС и т. д.), рекомендаций по качеству вопросов и другие важные обсуждения. Разумеется, включать туда какие-то вопросы, не имеющие долгосрочной значимости не следует.

А в будущем можно будет задествовать [функционал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1247/180450) [документации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1390/180450) для этого.

Comment: «Мета-Мету делать не нужно, ее будет читать такой же процент от читающих Мету, какой составляют читающие Мету от всех посетителей сайта.»

Comment: @NickVolynkin, даже если читают, то читают только новые вопросы. А то, что обсуждалось что-то полезное год назад, большинство знать не будет. Никто не читает старые вопросы, поскольку большинство из них имеют смысл либо в краткосрочном периоде, либо как справка по возникающим вопросам. Но не как дополнение к правилам.

Comment: [Часто задаваемые вопросы о StackOverflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кажется, она сама замечательно утонула... А вообще, там смесь распространённых вопросов, ссылок для комментариев и всего остального. В целом, годится, но надо бы как-то перегруппировать и дополнить.

Comment: пожалуйста, дополняйте )

Comment: Лишь дополню, что на Meta Stack Exchange поддерживается аналогичный вопрос «[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)».