# Вопрос к создателям Hashcode об условиях слияния с сетью StackExchange

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, хэшкод

Многим, кто читает вопросы тут, скорее всего известно, что ruSO был изначально создан на основе вопросов с русской площадки под названием Hashcode (вроде так, поправьте на правильное название, если нет). Т.е. сообщения, пользователи и т.п. из одной БД были "перекачены" в другую БД, а создатель Hashcode @NicolasChabanovsky стал руководителем данного сообщества в рамках сети StackExchange.

Непосредственно вопрос к Николаю (к остальным тоже, если они в курсе таких тонкостей): условия слияния с сетью SE оставляли за вами какую-либо независимость в принятии решений, в том числе в выборе направления для развития, без оглядки на некоторые положения других площадок SE? Всё-таки ruSO был "рождён" не в недрах SE, а вне его. Это его отличие имеет ли какое-либо преимущество по сравнению с остальными или нет?

## Обновление

Этот вопрос, об ограничениях и свободах отдельных площадок в отношении правил SE, уже поднимался на основной Meta и на нашей в виде перевода вопроса [Индивидуальные предпочтения сообщества против всеобщей политики SE: что сильнее?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7692)

Спасибо нашем заслуженному участнику [@VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd), который, несмотря на прекращение основной деятельности на ruSO, всё ещё продолжает помогать в виде дельных советов в сообщениях к основным вопросам и ответам. Как было и с упоминаем этой ссылки.

Из того вопроса следует, что свобода разных площадок всё-таки есть по отношению к SE, но насколько она большая (и насколько это правда) и насколько она отличалась от "свобод" других площадок в случае поглащения Hashcode? — вот в чём вопрос.

Comment: Немного информации о слиянии: https://vc.ru/story/11103-knowledge-network-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4):

Я не думаю, что тут нужен именно Николай. У него сейчас, как сотрудника, и так забот хватает.

Мы ничем не отличаемся от других сайтов сети.

- Все правила SE распространяются на нас.
- Мы должны их выполнять.
- Относительная автономия лишь по части контента.

Comment: Про последний член списка можно подробнее?

Comment: @edem мы сами можем решать причины закрытия, сами можем решать, что является онтопиком, к примеру.

Comment: А есть подробный список или где про это почитать?

Comment: @edem одного списка с этими решениями нет. И это тоже та ещё проблема с информированием участников по этим решениям.

Comment: Давайте создадим общий вопрос с ним. Что нам можно и как этим пользоваться.

Comment: @edem по теме: [Создание свода актуальных решений Меты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2090/15479).

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ваш ответ противоречит многим постам на англомете.

Comment: @VladD поделитесь ссылками?

Comment: @Suvitruf: Поищите одну в моих вопросах на этой Мете. Остальные искать мне не позволяет мое решение свернуть конструктивную деятельность на ru.SO.

Comment: @Suvitruf: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7692. Вы, кстати, в прошлой жизни принимали участие в переводе.

Comment: @VladD тот пост неоднозначный, т.к. никто не привёл ссылки о том, про что оригинальный пост - про весь сайт или только про контент.