# Документация: последние обновления

Tags: обсуждение, документация

[Несколько](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/) [месяцев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1390/) назад мы предложили расширить раздел Stack Overflow разделом **документации**. Запросы об обновлении статуса разработки поступали неоднократно, и наконец-то мы готовы его представить.

Но для начала…

## [Вы все еще можете успеть принять участие в бете!](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform)

С момента начала работы над бетой (середина ноября) мы уже разослали около тысячи приглашений. Если вы подписались, но не получили приглашения, не волнуйтесь – **приглашения получат все подписавшиеся**.

Во время работы над бета-версией мы узнали много нового и теперь имеем неплохое представление о том, как должна выглядеть первая версия нового раздела. Как результат, мы наконец–то можем прогнозировать, когда закончится работа над бетой: в один прекрасный апрельский день.

#### Это означает, что после 31-го марта *подписка* будет закрыта

Сама по себе работа над бетой продолжится еще какое-то время, поэтому вы все еще можете попасть в число приглашенных. К слову, документация не станет доступной на Stack Overflow с 1-го апреля.

## Чего новенького?

На момент выхода предыдущей публикации значительная часть функциональности была не готова; необходимость реализации некоторых функций обнаружилась в непосредственно в ходе работы.

Самые заметные обновления (в случайном порядке):

#### Возможность закрепления примеров

[image: Pinned examples]

Вверху каждой темы можно закрепить один самый важный относящийся к ней пример; остальные примеры располагаются в порядке убывания рейтинга. Мы предполагаем, что тема с бóльшим числом «самых важных примеров» заслуживает разделения на несколько тем.

#### Система репутации

Реализовано множество мелких улучшений, резюмируя:

[image: Reputation tour]

Естественно, сами себе репутацию вы повысить не сможете, и [удаления приводят к падению репутации точно так же, как в случае вопросов и ответов](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/). При выходе документации [из беты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/) репутация в разделе документации будет суммироваться с репутацией раздела вопросов и ответов.

#### Поиск документации в редакторе вопросов и ответов

[image: New link insertion]

Данное обновление облегчает добавление ссылок на документацию при написании ответов на вопросы. Текущая функциональность "Добавления гиперссылки" остается в силе.

#### «Битые» ссылки недопустимы

Согласитесь, «битые» ссылки на документацию (неважно где – в комментариях к коду, в публикациях блога, в «твитах») очень раздражают. И, конечно, вы бы хотели, чтобы документация (и ведущие к ней результаты поиска) со временем улучшались.

Дизайн, на котором мы остановились, выглядит следующим образом:

- По умолчанию, мы отображаем самые последние версий (включая выдачу «Ошибки 404» вместо удаленных тем): это означает, что Google индексирует только самую релевантную информацию.
- Но если у вас осталась устаревшая ссылка, мы хотим показывать вам версию, актуальную на момент размещения станицы.

Для **старых версий не удаленных тем** это выглядит следующим образом:

[image: Topic has since been edited]

**Удаленные темы** будут выглядеть так:

[image: Topic is currently deleted]

**Удаленные примеры** отображаются следующим образом:

[image: example is currently deleted]

При просмотре более ранних версий вверху страницы отображается небольшое предупреждение, при этом, невозможно вносить изменения и голосовать:

[image: Viewing an old version]

#### Расширенный список типов уведомлений

Очевидно необходимые уведомления:

- Мое изменение было одобрено/отклонено.
- Было предложено изменение к решению опубликованной мною проблемы.
- Кто-то прокомментировал опубликованную мною проблему или изменение.
- Кто-то ответил на один из моих комментариев.

В дополнение, на информационной панели раздела документации есть возможность подписаться на:

[image: Notification eyes]

При подписке на группу вы получаете *не более* одного уведомления за единицу времени. Если произошло несколько событий, требующих отправки уведомлений, мы стараемся рассылать каждое уведомление примерно равному числу адресатов.  Если событие, упоминаемое в уведомлении, теряет актуальность до того как пользователь открывает «Входящие», мы удаляем его, чтобы не засорять почту (в этом случае счет идет на мгновения, и, хотя мы стараемся, что-то может быть несовершенны).

#### Решайте, какими метки отметить документацию

Мы остановились на подходе [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Чтобы не плодить города-призраки, мы требуем, чтобы каждая метка использовалась хотя бы минимальным числом участников, работающих с разделом документации.

В бете это выглядит так:

[image: what commitments looks like]

Для Stack Overflow мы установили следующие пороговые значения:

- 10 участников;
- с репутацией 150 и более;
- хотя бы с одним положительно оцененным ответом по метке.

Участники, внесшие изменения, автоматически подписываются на обновления документации с соответствующей меткой; таким образом, всегда найдется тот, кто сможет отреагировать при появлении запроса на улучшение или изменение.

#### А также еще много всего интересного!

Эта публикация вышла довольно объемной, но в ней рассказывается далеко не все! При работе над бетой мы время от времени публиковали обновления, которые были собраны воедино (в обратном хронологическом порядке) в [доступный для всех документ](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nvUumvME1Q9upeD4T9cNpYv6bDSBXSXy3hQGLgxkUZI/edit?usp=sharing). Конечно, если вам интересен наш личный опыт…

#### [Подписывайтесь на бета документации!](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform)

...до 31 марта 2016 г.

---

Свободный перевод публикации «[Documentation: The Update-en-ing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/)»