# шапка за "заработайте репутацию за Документацию"

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

Что за Документация, где найти?

Comment: оффтоп на случай если developer story вам только ради шляпы: ее можно скрывать, шляпа останется) Справа сверху visibility: private.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, не ради шляпы, просто, смотрела за что какая шляпа дается и увидела "Документация". Не поняла что и где, вот решила спросить

Comment: я про developer story а не про документацию. Резюме то есть за которое у вас шляпа с собачкой)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, sorry не поняла)))) Да за это мне письма приходят и приходят - заполните ваше резюме, да и шляпа прикольная))

Comment: просто судя по вашему резюме, обучение в вузе было очень содержательным)) Вот я и предположил что это чисто для шляпы)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка типа ну наконец-то хоть где-то пригодилось образование?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, =)) вот в точку!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Новый раздел на английском сайте:

[***Документация***](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Подробнее про этот раздел можно посмотреть в посте:

[***Документация: последние обновления***](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2786/186999)

Comment: Нужно также учитывать что шапку можно заработать только на большом so. Показать здесь ее можно, но в шляпоретинге для ru.so: http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/ru.stackoverflow.com она учтена не будет

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, не уверен, что про рейтинг вообще что-то было :)

Comment: это просто указание что эта шапка немного отличается от остальных)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка так вот почему у меня там не 15 шляп.... хады!